# Allowing a unit to equip only certain types of weapons

Tags: c++

I'm making a FireEmblem style game, and I am working on items at the moment. I have a `Weapon` class from which `Sword`, `Axe`, etc. are derived. I also have character classes like `Swordsman`, `Mage`, etc. I would like to have a way to allow classes to only equip certain weapons (`Swordsman` can equip `Sword` but not `Axe`). One way I thought of was to have a global enum for `WeaponType`, and each weapon has a const `weapon_type` value. Then, each character class has a list of allowed `WeaponTypes` and you would check if a weapon's `weapon_type` is in the allowed list.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: This might be better suited on GameDesign.SE

Comment: @NathanOliver Not necessarily, let aside games, it's a question how to couple between corresponding class hierarchies.

Comment: Try to approach the problem from a relational point of view, not an object-oriented one. The problem is then trivial to solve; you'd have a "weapon" table, a "character" table and a "weapon_permission" table with foreign keys referencing the other two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed you have a function in your character base class that looks like

```
 class CharacterBase {
 public:
      bool equip(Weapon* weapon) {
          if(checkWeaponType(weapon)) {
              weapons.push_back(weapon);
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
 protected:
      virtual bool checkWeaponType(Weapon* weapon) const = 0;
 private:
      std::vector<Weapon*> weapons;
 };
```

you can provide an implementation that actually checks if the `Weapon` pointer passed has the correct type

```
 class SwordsMan : public CharacterBase {
 protected:
      virtual bool checkWeaponType(Weapon* weapon) const {
           return dynamic_cast<Sword*>(weapon) != nullptr;
      }
 };
```

Also let's suppose your `SwordsMan` character is also allowed to wear a `Dagger` then you extend your check like

```
      virtual bool checkWeaponType(Weapon* weapon) const {
           return dynamic_cast<Sword*>(weapon) != nullptr ||
                  dynamic_cast<Dagger*>(weapon) != nullptr ;
      }
```

Comment: This was another idea I had, but I'm wondering if there is an efficient method that does not require casting

Comment: @Chara You could use static polymorphism (introducing templates) as well, but for this case `dynamic_cast` seems to be more flexible steering in the corresponding class hierachies.

Comment: I see, this way is a lot easier than creating a string array/enum array of allowed weapon types anyways. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just spawning.

Lets say your allowed weapons are a string array in your class (string weaponAllow[10]).

And you weapons have names.
Make an object-array for your mage/warrior class (ill call it soldier).
Maybe when you have your equip function, or when you equip you say:

```
for(int a=0; a<=10; a++) {
    if(soldier[whichTypeOfSoldier].weaponAllow[a]==item[whichitem].name) {
        (code to equip the item)
    }
}
```

I take for granted that you have used object arrays, if not, i recommend using them.

Well, I was just spawning. Hopefully you get what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
struct WeaponAttributes {
    // Attributes to designate damage and weaknesses to
    // specific character classes and armor types.   
};

class Weapon {
public:
    enum WeaponClassType {
        WCT_SWORD,
        WCT_AXE,
        WCT_DAGGER,
        WCT_KNIFE,
        WCT_STAFF,
        /* WTC_ETC */
    };
private:
    std::string m_strWeaponClass;
    std::string m_strWeaponName;

    WeaponClassType m_WeaponClass;

public:
    // Constructor, Destructor and members this base class would have
    Weapon( const std::string& strWeaponClass, const std::string& strWeaponName, WeaponClassType weaponType );

    std::string getWeaponClassName() const;
    std::string getWeaponName() const;

    WeaponClassType getType() const;

    bool isWeaponType( const WeaponClassType& type ) const;
    bool isWeaponType( const std::string& strClassName ) const;

    void addAttributes( const WeaponAttributes& attributes ) = 0;          
};

class Sword : public Weapon {
private:
    WeaponAttributes m_attributes;

public:
    explicit Weapon( const std::string& strWeaponName );

    void addAttributes( const WeaponAttributes& attributes ) override;

};

struct CharacterAttributes {
    // Similar to WeaponAttributes
};

class Character {
public:
    enum CharacterClassType {
        CCT_FIGHTER,
        CCT_WARRIOR,
        CCT_MAGE,
        /* CCT_ETC */
    };

private:
    std::string m_strCharacterClassType;
    std::string m_strCharacterClassName;
    std::string m_strPlayerOrNPCName;

    CharacterClassType m_classType;

public:
    Character( const std::string& strName, const std::string& strClassName, const std::string strClassType, CharacterClassType classType );

    // Using Three Strings - Example: (Player's or NPC's game name, White, Mage )
    // (Player's or NPC's game name, Superior, Warrior )
    // (Player's or NPC's game name, Skilled, Fighter )
    std::string getName() const;
    std::string getClassName() const;
    std::string getCharacterName() const;

    CharacterClassType getCharacterType() const;

    bool isCharacterClassType( const CharacterClassType& type ) const;
    bool isCharacterClassType( const std::string& strClassType ) const;

    void addCharacterAttributes( const CharacterAtrributes& attributes ) = 0;
    bool equipWeapon( Weapon* pWeapon ) = 0;
    bool equipArmor( Armor* pArmor ) = 0;
};

class Character : public Fighter {
private:
    CharacterAttributes m_attributes;

    std::shared_ptr<Weapon> m_pWeapon;
    std::shared_ptr<Armor>  m_pArmor;

public:
     Fighter( const std::string& strPlayerOrNPCName, const std::string& strClassName );

     void addCharacterAttributes( const CharacterAttributes& attributes );
     bool equipWeapon( Weapon* pWeapon );
     bool equipArmor( Armor* pArmor );
};
```

With this type of class hierarchy and each class has an enum types and string descriptors along with methods to retrieve types, strings and to compare if they are specific type or not, you can easily traverse through different lists or vectors (containers) to see if a specific type of Armor or Weapon can be equipped to a specific class character. This is only one type of design method as there are many ways to implement such a system. I'm not boasting that this is the best or worst design method, but I feel that it serves as a great guide or starting point. Once you get the desired behavior that you want in a working stable state without any bugs, then and only then would it be time to modify your existing code base for optimization.